# Can't able to send multiple service requests from workflow in WF 4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've two workflows running as services in console applications and from workflow-1 I'm making two calls to workflow-2 through SendAndReceiveReply activity. Also, I'm using MessageCorrelation (by passing a GUID) to the workflow-2 so both the two calls from the workflow-1 are directed to the same workflow-2 instance. But the problem is the first call is getting succeeded while the second one fails. If I pass different GUIDs for each call then both the calls get succeeded.

Here is the exception,

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The operation could not be performed because WorlflowInstance '82h238-23j2392-23293j..' was aborted.
```

EDITED: The two calls are made from one branch of a parallel activity while the other branch has a delay activity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error message is pretty clear about the cause as it states that the other workflow is **aborted**. I presume this is because of an unhanded exception so the next step would be to debug that workflow and find out what the problem is that causes it to abort.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't see any problem with that workflow bcoz when I'm directly invoking it from WCFTestClient every thing seems fine. I think some kind of message correlation I've to do in workflow-1 on making two service calls to same workflow-2 instance. A single call is getting succeeded and two calls with different correlation key also getting succeeded but two calls with same key is failing.